# can't see log from python function execute from BashOperator - Airflow

Tags: python, airflow

I'm using apache airflow with `BashOperator`. 
Each `BashOperator` execute a python script.
For example:

```
from airflow.models import DAG
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator
with DAG(dag_id='dag_example', default_args=None,
             schedule_interval='0 2 */2 * *',
             catchup=False) as dag:

     run_task= BashOperator(
            task_id='simple_task',
            bash_command='python task.py',
            dag=dag)
```

Where `task.py` is:

```
import logging

def log_fun():
    logging.info('Log something')

if __name__=='__main__':
     log_fun()
```

I can't figure out why log doesn't appear in Airflow logs.
I checked `airflow.cfg` and logging_level is correctly set to INFO.

Answer (score 3):

Airflow's `BashOperator` will run your python script in a different process which is not reading your `airflow.cfg`. Because the default log level is `WARN` the logs don't appear in stdout and so don't show up in your Airflow logs.

Example:

```sh
$ cat task.py
import logging

def log_fun():
    logging.info('Log something')

if __name__=='__main__':
     log_fun()
$ python task.py
$
```

If you add the log level explicitly in your Python file the logs will show up:

```
$ cat task2.py
import logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

def log_fun():
    logging.info('Log something')

if __name__=='__main__':
     log_fun()
$ python task2.py
INFO:root:Log something
$
```

That being said, I think that the better solution would be to use a `PythonOperator` rather than a `BashOperator`. It should use the same logging configuration which you are setting up in your `airflow.cfg` as it won't run in a separate process.

Comment: Can't use a PythonOperator due to code dependencies. I'm pretty disappointed on this matter, it seems that no one cares. Packaged dags is not a viable solution ( dynamic libraries), VirtualEnvOperator create and destroy approach is not feasible. At the end I stick to BashOperator calling virtualenv python interpreter to execute my script.